# VSCode Debugger does not work. Ends immedately and cannot step through despite setting break points

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

Here's the code itself. Very simple

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int one = 4;
    int x = 7;
    std::cout << "111Hiiiiiiklfjglksjfdlk!";
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
111Hiiiiiiklfjglksjfdlk![1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-6sebtwga.65e" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-tmjr1ovo.jg1"
```

Here's the launch.json

```
{

// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes. 
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes. 
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387 
"version": "0.2.0", 
"configurations": [ 
{ "name": "(gdb) Launch", 
"type": "cppdbg", 
"request": "launch", 
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out", "args": [], 
"stopAtEntry": false, 
"cwd": "${fileDirname}", 
"environment": [], 
"externalConsole": false, 
"MIMode": "gdb", 
"setupCommands": [ { "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb", 
"text": "-enable-pretty-printing", 
"ignoreFailures": false } ] 
}

]

}
```

I compile through the terminal with g++ *.cpp and run with ./a.out

It doesn't compile when I hit run, only runs the previous build.

I cannot step through. I could set break points and the gdb even acknowledges I create breakpoints but the darn thing just exits

And here's the debugger output:

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555189 in main ()
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
[Inferior 1 (process 66190) exited normally]
The program '/home/jared/GROWTH/a.out' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

Comment: Most debuggers are line-oriented. Put each statement in your program on a separate line.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was. That was just bad formatting on my part

Comment: you don't compile with debugging enabled, now the debugger has NO idea where your lines start, search for the correct command line option for your compiler, don't start the program with `./a.out` but let VSC launch the debugger with the program